# How to find dense region for a given data

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I have some data in 2 and 3 dimensions which is dense in some of the regions. I want to identify the location (e.g. what are coordinates) of dense regions.  How can I do it in MATLAB?

Comment: Is it discrete or continuous? Can you provide a snippet of the data in a Matlab form? Also are you only concerned with the data locations or will your density also need to consider the data values as well?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `ksdensity`?

Comment: @Dan It is continuous, I am just concerned about the data location based on the density.

Comment: @namanarora sounds like you just want a sort of histogram of the locations. Choose a bin size (i.e. discrete resolution) and just count how many points fall in each bin. You might find it effective to choose a smaller bin size and apply some sort of blur function (e.g. a low pass filter) to smooth out the results. In 2D such a smoothing function could look like `conv2(X, ones(n)/n, 'same')` (use `convn` for 3d I'd guess) or you could use a gaussian kernel instead of that linear one (the `ones(n)/n`) perhaps

Comment: @Dan Yes I need this one. Problem is solved.

Comment: @namanarora please post your solution (preferably with code) as an answer to this question for future viewers

Answer (score 1):

`stack=[
    0.3377   13.2877
    0.9998   12.4943
    0.9510   12.4842
    0.9574   13.9244
    0.9777   13.2662
    0.9979   13.1708
    0.9875   13.1157
    0.9031   13.6960
    0.9960   12.4719
    0.9979   13.6824
    1.0000   13.7335
    0.7812   14.2022
    0.9998   14.7640
    0.9945   13.1227
    0.9999   13.3503
    1.0000   12.8568
    0.9999   12.3256
    0.6345   13.0517
    0.9820   13.4894
    0.9999   12.5354
    0.8559   13.3108
    0.9970   13.7586
    0.8116   13.8012
    0.9323   13.0256
    0.9423   13.5361
    0.7019   13.2854
    0.9819   13.6477
    0.9804   12.4863
    0.7669   12.8813
    0.8885   13.6194
    0.9853   12.9060
    0.9400   12.8526
    0.2850   12.9174
    0.9994   13.9772
    0.9890   13.1104
    0.9989   13.3893
    0.7888   13.2719
    0.4071   13.5379
    0.9998   12.2532
    1.0000   14.2750
    0.9996   11.4092
    0.9939   13.4314
    1.0000   12.5144
    0.9959   12.5110
    0.9999   13.5899
    1.0000   14.0406
    0.9828   13.1062
    0.9663   12.8354
    0.9649   13.2215
    0.9705   13.4326
    1.0000   13.6262
    0.9967   12.8675
    0.9079   14.1104
    0.9020   13.2061
    0.9503    9.5147
    0.8886   14.3950
    0.9958   13.3653
    0.9995   12.2215
    0.9752   12.8164
    0.6447   12.6994
    1.0000   12.9172
    0.9076   14.0845
    0.8153   13.4479
    0.9781   13.2565
    0.9822   12.7920
    1.0000   12.7281
    1.0000   13.8138
    0.9417   11.8934
    0.9960   12.4767
    0.9998   13.0682
    1.0000   13.6342
    1.0000   13.4196
    0.9952   12.3487
    1.0000   13.8783
    1.0000   14.2286
    0.8499   13.5785
    0.9979   13.7113
    1.0000   12.8141
    0.9811   12.0216
    0.9007   12.6659
    0.9932   14.1992
    0.9934   13.4345
    0.9906   12.8330
    0.9681   14.0795
    0.7585   13.9392
    0.3921   12.5298
    0.8948   13.2342]`
and I used hist3(stack) to see the distribution of points. Now I can see where is high dense region